# electron-windows-installer slow execution

Tags: node.js, npm, electron

I'm doing some deployment tests in windows and I'm using "electron-windows-installer" package to create a windows installer from my electron app.

I did it as a gulp task.

```
 'use strict';

 var gulp = require('gulp');
 var winInstaller = require('electron-windows-installer');

 gulp.task('create-windows-installer', function(done) {
    winInstaller({
        appDirectory: 'build/myApp',
        outputDirectory: 'build/release',
        iconUrl: 'URIToIcon',
        exe: 'myApp.exe',
        title: 'myApp',
        setupExe: 'myApp.exe',
        setpMsi: 'myApp.msi',
        setupIcon: 'pathToIcon',
        loadingGif: 'pathToGif',
        arch: 'ia32'
    }).then(done).catch(done);
 });
```

And my package.json has the following command to run it from npm

```
    "installer": "gulp windows-installer"
```

When I do npm run installer everything is working but the execution to create this installer is about 1 hour and 10 minutes. I have 52 dependencies in my project and my final executable is about 200MB. I'm wondering if it's normal that this process takes so long or something is bad in my code.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The process take too long because of the cache of folders/files to new build.
Just clean the outputDirectory (either appDirectory if necessary) and then build again, you'll good to go.